# How to create a fixed QDateTime from a string?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I create a fixed time for testing purposes?

I'm thinking something like:

```
static QDateTime startTime = "2001-02-03 14:55:02"
```

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Why not `const`?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe that would work as well.

Comment: Maybe the title is better worded as: How to construct a QDateTime from string?

Comment: I edited my question to something similar, but kept some of my obvious wording as that was what I actually searched for without finding anything at a quick google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Qt docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html

```
static QDateTime starttime = QDateTime::fromString("2001-02-03 14:55:02");
```

might be what you are looking for.

A QDateTime can be parsed from a string using the static member function `QDateTime::fromString()` this class function, creates a QDateTime internally, intializes it from parsing the string and returning The QDateTime it created.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. It seems like the correct syntax is QDateTime::fromString("2001-02-03 14:55:02")

Comment: @user1283776 yes sorry, i've been doing a lot of python recently and this sometimes troubles my C++ ability.